# Android - Test For "Well Formed" Valid XML on import

Tags: java, android, xml, validation

I am importing a Standard XML on startup into my application that is used to save and recall application parameters.

The XML is updated onPause() however if the application crashes for any reason the resulting XML may not be valid.

I would like to be able to test to see if the XML is valid and if not then use generic settings.

Q: How can I test the XML to see if it is valid?

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DecisionList>
 <ExampleSet1>
  <Value1> 1.0 </Value1>
 </ExampleSet1>
</DecisionList>
```

Main Activity

```
public class MyActivity  extends Activity  implements OnItemSelectedListener{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        MyActivity_Preflight.Setup();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
     // .......
 }
 }
```

PreFlight Activity

```
public class MyActivity_Preflight {

public static void Setup() throws Exception{

try{
XPathFactory  factory=XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath=factory.newXPath();

File pathTmp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myApp/Tmp" );
File xmlDocument = new File( pathTmp + "/tmp.xml");

/*
*  Chk to see if XML is Valid Statement block Here
*    if Valid then Continue
*/

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(xmlDocument));
XPathExpression  tag_Value1 = xPath.compile("/DecisionList/ExampleSet1/Value1");
String Value1 = tag_Value1.evaluate(inputSource);
GlobalVariables.setSeekBarValue1(Float.valueOf(Value1));

// if (XMLisNotValid)
// GlobalVariables.setSeekBarValue1(1.0f);

  }
 }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate using [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html)

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
db.parse(pathTmp + "/tmp.xml");
```

If XML parses then its a valid XML, if not its not a valid XML.

Comment: Thanks Jayamohan, how would I return a true or false boolean output of the documentBuilderFactory parse method. Ie if it does parse then true. Thanks.

Comment: You should be getting `SAXException` as per API if there is any issues in the XML.

Comment: Thanks again, Are you able to give me an example of handling a SAXException when given a malformed XML wherebby instead I can load settings from another method. Many Thanks.